# Solve $x(dy/dx) = x^4y^3 - y $ (Bernoulli's equations)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Use method of Bernoulli's equations to solve the equation:

$$ x(dy/dx) = x^4y^3 - y $$

I don't really can understand how to use Bernoulli's equations as I had it only once and I wasn't able to understand it then. Can someone guide me through the way of solving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$xy'+y = x^4y^3 $$
$$y'+\frac yx = x^3y^3 $$
$$y'+\frac yx = x^3y^m  \implies m=3$$
Divide by $y^3$
$$\frac {y'}{y^3}+\frac 1{xy^2} = x^3 $$
Then you can use Bernouilli's technics.

Substitute  $u(x)=y^{1-m}=y^{-2} \implies u'(x)=-2y^{-3}y'$

The equation becomes linear of first order in u
$$-\frac 12u'+\frac ux=x^3$$

***Another approach***, the original equation is separable :
$$x(dy/dx) = x^4y^3 - y$$
$$ \implies xy'+y = x^4y^3  \implies (xy)' = x(xy)^3 $$
Simpli integrate :
$$ \int \frac {d (xy)}{(xy)^3}=\int xdx $$

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation is really really clear

Comment: yw James... i am happy of it helped you..@JamesSmith

Answer (score 1):

The idea is " separating the variables" :

So you write your original equation and set a set $A$ where $y$ doesn't take null values (and $x \neq 0 $) :

Let $y$ such a solution.

Let $u$ a function so that: $$u=xy(x)$$

The equation becomes

$$ u'=xu^3$$

So $$ \frac{u'(x)}{u^3(x)}=x  $$

You guess .. :)

So $$ \int \frac{u'(x)}{u^3(x)} dx = \frac{x^2}{2} + \varpi  $$
$$ u^2(x)=\dfrac{-1}{\varpi+\frac{x^2}{2}} $$

Then discuss values of definition.